# Get reference of custom Logger wrapper class with LogManager.getLogger()

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm using Log4j2 and the default logger implementation has been widely used in my project. I now have a requirement to parse the log message and replace certain keywords before logging them to log files. A good approach for this requirement might be to override the logger methods like `info()`, `error()`,... or their underlying low level methods where I can parse the message and modify it and then call the original super class logger method.

I see that `AbstractLogger` class is the implementation class for the `Logger` interface and when you do `Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();` in your class, you get a reference of the `AbstractLogger` class.

Now, I created a class `CustomLogger` that extends `AbstractLogger` whose javadoc says to do so:

> Base implementation of a Logger. It is highly recommended that any
>   Logger implementation extend this class.

The question is, how to make `LogManager.getLogger()` to return reference of my  `CustomLogger` class instead of the `AbstractLogger` class, so that the log statements in my existing classes need not be modified and I get the ability to parse and modify the messages before they are logged. Currently I continue to get the AbstractLogger reference. I am trying to know how Log4j intended users to extend its implementation.

Comment: have you considered doing this in the output, i.e. in an appender?

Comment: ... or a formatter, of course.

Comment: @rmalchow that's a great tip which I did not think about. I handled it now in the appender and it works. You could add an answer with a sample and I can give you the credits, if you would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment - I think that an appender might be a better place to do this. This would mean that you would have to implement

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender
```

or extend from

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender
```

and change it's

```
public void append(LogEvent event) {}
```

method. Depending on your needs, you could also modify or copy some other appender class (unfortunately, some of them are declared final) and modify it accordingly.

.rm

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say RTM but this is a case of RTM. The below should help you get started on what you want. Specifically looking in to the bottom for the first link on how to compile a customer logger.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customloglevels.html

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/tools/Generate.CustomLogger.html

Comment: I already referred to those links but did not find it useful. If you see the section: [Example Usage of a Generated Logger Wrapper](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customloglevels.html#ExampleUsage) to get a reference to your custom class, you must use something like `private static final ExtLogger logger = ExtLogger.create(MyService.class);` which doesn't match my requirement to use the LogManager.getLogger() to get the custom logger class reference.